# How to revokes some scopes in Google OAuth 2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Google OAuth 2.0 supports "[**Incremental Authorization**](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#incrementalAuth)", which allows us to dynamically add the requests for authorization to access more resources, which are identified by **scopes**. Is it possible to do oppositely? Can I dynamically remove some **scopes**? For example, currently Users have authorized our app to access Gmail and Drive. Later, Users want to allow Gmail Access Only. We need to remove Drive access. How can we do it? Is there anything like **Decremental Authorization**?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've seen there is no way to have a **Decremental Authorization**. In fact it's also not possible to revoke with many of the providers without trashing the tokens. Only way to do it in the specific scenario is to ask the user to re authorize. :(

You probably already know this (link to revoke):)
[https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke?token={token}](https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke?token=%7Btoken%7D)

To dig in a bit more, why would you want to remove access. Can you give me a use case?

Background: I work at Pathfix and we deal with OAuth on a regular basis

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Revoking the access token is a way but the access in https://myaccount.google.com/permissions is not removed. This makes users misunderstood that we still access to their resource.
I want to remove access because when users disable a function in my apps that is able to access a resource on Google, the access SHOULD be removed

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to vote up your comment now